# My print statement just won't run even when there aren't any errors in the output and it's hard to trace the error

Tags: python, printing

> Blockquote

```
Age = int(input("Enter your age"))
Day = input("WD or WE")
Upgrade = input("Do you want to upgrade?")
Month = input("Enter the month you're going in")

#Age_Group
if Age > 12:
    Age_Group = "Adult"
else:
    Age_Group = "Child"

#Month
if Month == "November":
    if Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WD":
        Price = 46
    elif Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WE":
        Price = 55
    elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WD":
        Price = 34
    elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WE":
        Price = 42

else:
     if Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WD":
        Price = 69
     elif Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WE":
        Price = 79
     elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WD":
        Price = 53
     elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WE":
        Price = 59

if Upgrade == "Yes":
 if Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WD":
    FinalPrice = Price + 46
    print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")

elif Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WE":
    FinalPrice = Price +  55
    print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
        
elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WD":
    FinalPrice = Price + 34
    print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
        
elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WE":
    FinalPrice = Price + 42
    print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
else:

    if Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WD":
        FinalPrice = Price 
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
    elif Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WE":
        FinalPrice = Price 
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
    elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WD":
        FinalPrice = Price 
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
    elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WE":
        FinalPrice = Price 
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
```

This is my first time posting on stack overflow so I have no idea how to properly format the post or ir if i'm doing it right so please bear with me. The code malfunctions when I input "15", "WE", "Yes" and November respectively, as such that the print statement just wouldn't run and nothing would be outputted from the code but i can't find the source of the error for the life of me and the lack off errors in the output isn't helping either.  This is the line that won't run

elif Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WE":
Price = 55

Comment: You broke branched out in your if upgrade. check your indents

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your indentation is incorrect, and this is hard to see because the code's formatting (and indentation) is not regular:

```py
if Upgrade == "Yes":
 if Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WD":
    FinalPrice = Price + 46
    print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")

elif Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WE":
    FinalPrice = Price +  55
    print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
```

Here, if we indent the code correctly (to 4 space) we get

```py
if Upgrade == "Yes":
    if Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WD":
        FinalPrice = Price + 46
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
elif Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WE":
    FinalPrice = Price +  55
    print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
```

That is, if `"Upgrade"` is "Yes", then it will check if the age group is "Adult" and the day is "WD". Since that's not the case (the day is "WE"), nothing will happen.

And since the following `elif` clauses and the final `else` are all un-intented, they are attached to the `if Upgrade` clause, so they're skipped. You should indent the inner `if` properly, and reindent all the `elif` to match:

```py
if Upgrade == "Yes":
    if Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WD":
        FinalPrice = Price + 46
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")

    elif Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WE":
        FinalPrice = Price +  55
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
        
    elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WD":
        FinalPrice = Price + 34
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
        
    elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WE":
        FinalPrice = Price + 42
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
else:
    ...
```

The core architecture also makes this sort of errors more likely: the entire thing is purely data-driven based on age, DoW, and month, with an additional step for the upgrade. So the entire thing would be much simplified by defining price determination as a table (or hashmap) e.g.

```py
from enum import Enum

Age = int(input("Enter your age"))
Day_ = input("WD or WE")
Upgrade = input("Do you want to upgrade?")
Month = input("Enter the month you're going in")

class AgeGroup(Enum):
    ADULT = 1
    CHILD = 2
class Day(Enum):
    WE = 1
    WD = 2

TABLE = {
    "November": {
        (AgeGroup.ADULT, Day.WD): 56,
        (AgeGroup.ADULT, Day.WE): 55,
        (AgeGroup.CHILD, Day.WD): 34,
        (AgeGroup.CHILD, Day.WE): 42,
    },
    None: { # defaults
        (AgeGroup.ADULT, Day.WD): 69,
        (AgeGroup.ADULT, Day.WE): 79,
        (AgeGroup.CHILD, Day.WD): 53,
        (AgeGroup.CHILD, Day.WE): 59,
    },
}
UPGRADES = {
    (AgeGroup.ADULT, Day.WD): 46,
    (AgeGroup.ADULT, Day.WE): 55,
    (AgeGroup.CHILD, Day.WD): 34,
    (AgeGroup.CHILD, Day.WE): 42,
}

age_group = AgeGroup.ADULT if Age > 12 else AgeGroup.CHILD
day = Day[Day_]

prices = TABLE.get(Month) or TABLE[None]
price = prices[age_group, day]
if Upgrade == 'Yes':
    price += UPGRADES[age_group, day]
print(f"You have to pay {price}")
```

Having a data-driven structure makes it much easier to:

- catch errors (hashmaps will raise an exception on incorrect key accesses, and limiting conditionals makes it much harder to get them wrong and unwittingly skip code)
- check that all conditions have a case and the values are correct
- eventually migrate from the data being embedded in code to the data being in an external pure data file, which would make the oversight and update easier

Comment: I think he needs to indent the following 3 elif statements as well. as now the code ends when upgrade == "Yes"

Comment: @Henkes fair point, that was clear in my head but implicit in the post, I put it more explicitly with a properly indented version of the code as demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

The condition 'elif Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WE": Price = 55' is falling under the scope of 'if Upgrade == "Yes":'. That's why your elif condition is not getting called. You want to keep your elif within the scope of 'if Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WD":' which is just below 'if Upgrade == "Yes":'. Following will work:

```
if Upgrade == "Yes":
    if Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WD":
        FinalPrice = Price + 46
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")

    elif Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WE":
        FinalPrice = Price + 55
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")

    elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WD":
        FinalPrice = Price + 34
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")

    elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WE":
        FinalPrice = Price + 42
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
else:

    if Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WD":
        FinalPrice = Price
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
    elif Age_Group == "Adult" and Day == "WE":
        FinalPrice = Price
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
    elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WD":
        FinalPrice = Price
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
    elif Age_Group == "Child" and Day == "WE":
        FinalPrice = Price
        print(f"You have to pay {FinalPrice}")
```